# how do I add openlayers as a library to my oracle jet project?

Tags: openlayers, oracle-jet

I created an oracle jet project using ojet create, build, serve commands. Alternatively, I have also created the project using NetBeans 8.2 IDE. I am not able to add open layers as a library. I want to create a web application which would consist of maps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you are not able to add the library, as you haven't specified how 
you tried to add it and what was the error, if any.

This is what I would do:

1. After `ojet create` run the command `npm install --save ol`. This adds the library in your node_modules folder and also adds it to your package.json. If you don't want to add it to your package.json use only `npm install ol`.
2. Navigate to scripts folder -> config folder -> oraclejet-build.js. See the commented lines 37 to 45? Uncomment those lines and add your own library paths, like this:

   ```
   copyCustomLibsToStaging: {
     fileList: [
      {
        cwd:'node_modules/ol/',
        src: ['*'],
        dest: 'web/js/libs/ol'
      }
     ]
    },
   ```
3. You can now access your library by using the require module. Assuming you created an ojet project using a template, you can provide access to this library from the 'main.js' file.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer @Ray. I just started with oracle jet. I am trying to provide access to the library from main.js. I tried giving different paths but it always gives me an error in the browser. A script error saying that it cannot load this path. Tried building before, but did not work.

Comment: oh.. you mean it's still not working? could you show your main.js and your file structure? best case would be to just somehow give the entire project folder itself...

Comment: how do I send you the project folder itself?

Answer (score 0):

My main.js file looks like this..

```
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2014, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates.
 * The Universal Permissive License (UPL), Version 1.0
 */
'use strict';

/**
 * Example of Require.js boostrap javascript
 */

requirejs.config(
{
  baseUrl: 'js',

  // Path mappings for the logical module names
  // Update the main-release-paths.json for release mode when updating the mappings
  paths:
  //injector:mainReleasePaths
  {
    'knockout': 'libs/knockout/knockout-3.4.0.debug',
    'jquery': 'libs/jquery/jquery-3.1.1',
    'jqueryui-amd': 'libs/jquery/jqueryui-amd-1.12.0',
    'promise': 'libs/es6-promise/es6-promise',
    'hammerjs': 'libs/hammer/hammer-2.0.8',
    'ojdnd': 'libs/dnd-polyfill/dnd-polyfill-1.0.0',
    'ojs': 'libs/oj/v3.2.0/debug',
    'ojL10n': 'libs/oj/v3.2.0/ojL10n',
    'ojtranslations': 'libs/oj/v3.2.0/resources',
    'text': 'libs/require/text',
    'signals': 'libs/js-signals/signals',
    'customElements': 'libs/webcomponents/CustomElements',
    'proj4': 'libs/proj4js/dist/proj4-src',
    'css': 'libs/require-css/css',
  }
  //endinjector
  ,
  // Shim configurations for modules that do not expose AMD
  shim:
  {
    'jquery':
    {
      exports: ['jQuery', '$']
    }
  }
}
);

/**
 * A top-level require call executed by the Application.
 * Although 'ojcore' and 'knockout' would be loaded in any case (they are specified as dependencies
 * by the modules themselves), we are listing them explicitly to get the references to the 'oj' and 'ko'
 * objects in the callback
 */
require(['ojs/ojcore', 'knockout', 'appController', 'ojs/ojknockout',
  'ojs/ojmodule', 'ojs/ojrouter', 'ojs/ojnavigationlist', 'ojs/ojbutton', 'ojs/ojtoolbar','libs/ol'],
  function (oj, ko, app) { // this callback gets executed when all required modules are loaded

    $(function() {

      function init() {
        oj.Router.sync().then(
          function () {
            // Bind your ViewModel for the content of the whole page body.
            ko.applyBindings(app, document.getElementById('globalBody'));
          },
          function (error) {
            oj.Logger.error('Error in root start: ' + error.message);
          }
        );
      }

      // If running in a hybrid (e.g. Cordova) environment, we need to wait for the deviceready 
      // event before executing any code that might interact with Cordova APIs or plugins.
      if ($(document.body).hasClass('oj-hybrid')) {
        document.addEventListener("deviceready", init);
      } else {
        init();
      }

    });

  }
);
```

Comment: ok.. so did you try adding something like 'ol': 'libs/ol' to the main release paths?
You could zip your project without the node_modules folder and share it on github or any other similar public platform

Comment: Sorry. My bad. Here you go.. https://github.com/vikrameswar/ojetBasic2.git

Comment: @Ray sent you a message on Quora. Please check it out :)

Comment: Would be really helpful if you send me a project folder where an openlayer map is implemented through oracle jet. Sorry about all these requests :/

Comment: @Ray I figured it out. Looks like requireJS blocks the openlayers library somehow (maybe they are not compatible ?). So I had to add the import statements in the index.html file and then in the js view model file of the module, insert the map code in the handleattached function.

Comment: hi there.. sorry for the delay. Good to hear it worked out :) although i don't think it's a compatibility issue, since we have added numerous libraries to our oraclejet projects in my office. I'll reply to the Quora message and have a look at the new project on Github as well, and try to configure it right for you :)

Comment: Thanks a lot @Ray, looks like the message on Quora has been deleted for some reason. This is my email, if you are interested :) vikram.eswar@gmail.com.

Comment: @Ray could you please help me out with this ?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53444785/oracle-jet-persist-button-set-states-in-list-view-items-models-on-sorting